# how to spark streaming use connection pool for impala(JDBC to kudu)

Tags: spark-streaming, impala

i use impala(JDBC) twice to get kafka offset and save data in foreachRDD.
but impala and kudu always shutdown. now i want to set connect pool, but little for scala.
it's my pseudo-code:

```
#node-1
val newOffsets = getNewOffset() // JDBC read kafka offset in kudu
val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(*,newOffsets,)

messages.foreachRDD(rdd => {

      val spark = SparkSession.builder.config(rdd.sparkContext.getConf).getOrCreate()

      #node-2
      Class.forName(jdbcDriver)
      val con = DriverManager.getConnection("impala url")
      val stmt = con.createStatement()
       stmt.executeUpdate(sql)

      #node-3
       val offsetRanges = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges
      offsetRanges.foreach { r => {
        val rt_upsert = s"UPSert into ${execTable} values('${r.topic}',${r.partition},${r.untilOffset})"
        stmt.executeUpdate(rt_upsert)

        stmt.close()
       conn.close()
      }}





}
```

how to code by c3p0 or other ? I'll appreciate your help.

Comment: why you are using impala to store offsets of Kafka,you can either the zookeeper to store offset or  enable Kafka only to save offset and to insert data to kudu use data frame writer or kudu context

Comment: yes, but use kudu api may be slower than java jdbc

Comment: I already using kudu context i am able to push data at least 10k messages for second

Comment: is there a way to exec sql by kudu context?

Comment: yes you write execute the query using kudu context

Comment: i update my pseudo-code,could you give me a simple, very thanks!

Comment: i had answered your question with some working code you can use that

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code for reading data from kafka and inserting the data to kudu.

```
import kafka.message.MessageAndMetadata
import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder
import org.apache.kudu.client.KuduClient
import org.apache.kudu.client.KuduSession
import org.apache.kudu.client.KuduTable
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Milliseconds,
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils

import scala.collection.immutable.List
import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.util.control.NonFatal
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SQLContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.kudu.Schema
import org.apache.kudu.Type._
import org.apache.kudu.spark.kudu.KuduContext

import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
object KafkaKuduConnect extends Serializable {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    try {
      val TopicName="TestTopic"
      val kafkaConsumerProps = Map[String, String]("bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9092")
      val KuduMaster=""
      val KuduTable=""
      val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("KafkaKuduConnect")

      val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

      val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

      import sqlContext.implicits._

      val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Milliseconds(1000))

      val kuduContext = new KuduContext(KuduMaster, sc)

      val kuduclient: KuduClient = new KuduClient.KuduClientBuilder(KuduMaster).build()
      //Opening table
      val kudutable: KuduTable = kuduclient.openTable(KuduTable)
      // getting table schema
      val tableschema: Schema = kudutable.getSchema
      // creating the schema for the data frame using the table schema
      val FinalTableSchema =generateStructure(tableschema)


    //To create the schema for creating the data frame from the rdd
      def generateStructure(tableSchema:Schema):StructType=
      {
        var structFieldList:List[StructField]=List()
        for(index <-0 until tableSchema.getColumnCount)
        {
          val col=tableSchema.getColumnByIndex(index)
          val coltype=col.getType.toString
          println(coltype)
          col.getType  match {
            case INT32  =>
              structFieldList=structFieldList:+StructField(col.getName,IntegerType)
            case STRING  =>
              structFieldList=structFieldList:+StructField(col.getName,StringType)
            case _  =>
              println("No Class Type Found")
          }
        }
        return StructType(structFieldList)
      }

      // To create the Row object with values type casted according to the schema
      def getRow(schema:StructType,Data:List[String]):Row={
        var RowData=ArrayBuffer[Any]()
        schema.zipWithIndex.foreach(
          each=>{
            var Index=each._2
            each._1.dataType  match {
              case IntegerType=>
                if(Data(Index)=="" | Data(Index)==null)
                  RowData+=Data(Index).toInt

              case StringType=>
                RowData+=Data(Index)
              case _=>
                RowData+=Data(Index)
            }
          }
        )
        return Row.fromSeq(RowData.toList)
      }


      val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaConsumerProps, Set(TopicName))
      messages.foreachRDD(
        //we are looping through eachrdd 
        eachrdd=>{
          //we are creating the Rdd[Row] to create dataframe with our schema 
         val StructuredRdd= eachrdd.map(eachmessage=>{
           val record=eachmessage._2
           getRow(FinalTableSchema, record.split(",").toList)
         })
          //DataFrame with required structure according to the table.
          val DF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(StructuredRdd, FinalTableSchema)
          kuduContext.upsertRows(DF,KuduTable)
        }
      )

    }
    catch {
      case NonFatal(e) => {
        print("Error in main : " + e)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks. but i have a question that only define spark context in messages.foreachRDD for spark 2.0. Could you see my code again because i update that ?

Comment: @Autumn can you explain what you need.i did not understand

Comment: i need to  read kudu by JDBC three times: (1) before KafkaUtils.createDirectStream, i get kafka offset by JDBC; (2) in messages.foreachRDD, Business  sql ;(3)in messages.foreachRDD, save kafka latest offset into kudu. you could see my pseudo-code: